# How to change one element value with Protractor? Is there any method to do that?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, import, protractor

I am testing a project using Protractor. The project contains badges ans elements with two way binding properties.

Lets say that there is a element with a value of 10, and i want it to change to 5 to then test if the value changes. Is there any method or option to do that with protractor?

The only way i know is to change text with sendKeys, but thats for inputs.

ex:

```
<ion-badge class="badge badge-md">4</ion-badge>
```

How do i change the value 4 of that badge?

Answer (score 0):

innerHTML will help

browser.executeScript('document.querySelector("ion-badge").innerHTML = 9);

https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.executeScript

[image]